# How do I close the console window when a user quits?

Tags: c, visual-studio

My program requires the user to input a choice of trying again or quitting the program. When the user inputs 'y/Y' he/she can try again and if the user inputs 'q/Q' the program quits. Im not sure how to code my program such that if the user inputs q the console window closes automatically.

Also I have another problem, whenever the user inputs 'y/Y' the "Do you wish to try again?  Invalid option." line automatically appears after all the calculations are done. It should not be there. I think there's a slight mistake in my coding but im not sure which part is wrong.

Here is a screenshot of that error:

[image]

Here are part of the codes that code this specific function:

```
while (1)
{
    /*Making sure vertices entered by user are valid*/
    if (!Invalid) {
        printf("Please choose a node:\n");
        scanf_s("%d", &i);

        if (0 <= i && i <= 20){
            print_index(i);
            Invalid = true;
        }
        else {
            printf("Error! Please enter a valid node.\n");
        }
    }
    /*Prompt user to try again or quit the program*/
    if (Invalid) {
        printf("\nDo you wish to try again? <Type Y to continue or Q to quit>\n");
        scanf_s("%c", &End_Program);

        if (End_Program == 'q' || End_Program == 'Q') {//user can input q or Q
            printf("\nThank you!\n");
            printf("==============================\n\n");
            getchar();
        }
        else if (End_Program == 'y' || End_Program == 'Y') {//user can continue
            Repeat = true;
            Invalid = false;
        }
        else {
            printf("Invalid option.\n");
            Invalid = true;
            Repeat = true;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Please upgrade to a [mcve].

Comment: Do you open the console window manually? I.e. do you open a "DOS prompt" (or what it's called now) and explicitly type in the name of your program to run it? Or do you run it from inside Visual Studio (running with e.g. `Ctrl-F5` or debugging with `F5`)?

Comment: You never terminate your loop. Either `break` from it or use a condition other that `1`.

Comment: After seeing the image (please don't post images of text, copy paste it!) it seems one of your problems is the usual `scanf` with the `%c` format problem. If you do some searching for `scanf` and reading characters you will find out what the problem is.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude hello i run it from visual studio

Comment: Lastly, learning how to use the Visual Studio debugger (which is excellent) then you could step through the code line by line and see what's happening and what is read by your `scanf_s` call, and why the loop will never end.

Comment: @EugeneSh. how do i break from it?

Comment: To use `break` ? If you don't know how, you should read about it.

Comment: I would say, please *don't* have your program close the window when the user quits!  What if the user wants to refer to something in the window?  Let the user close the window themselves when they're ready to, that's my vote.  Windows that close too soon are incredibly annoying.  (Half the beginner programs you see here on SO have extra little nonporable calls to `getch()` inserted at the end of `main()`, which as far as I know are there just to keep the window open until the user is ready to close them.)

Comment: @SteveSummit hello sir actually its part of my assignment requirement its not something i can choose or not so yeah

Answer (score 0):

You need to put *"return 0;"* at the end of the if where you verified if the user wants to quit and it will stop the code.